# Tailwind CSS breakpoints inverted somehow?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm testing Tailwind CSS, and I'm facing this issue. It was working before and it's still working in some cases, but on this line below its inverting the breakpoints somehow. See the screenshots below

**Example code:**

```html
<h1 className='sm:text-4xl text-8xl'>
  AndiiCodes<span className="dot">.</span>
</h1>
```

Full screen (text should be 8xl, but it's taking the `sm:` size of 4xl): [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYpve.png)

Medium/small screens: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXel3.png)

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
  "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  'node_modules/flowbite-react/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    require('flowbite/plugin'),
  ],
}
```

**CSS file**

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

I also tried to set a base font size first then change it on other screens, but I'm still running into the same issue.

Comment: `sm:text-4xl text-8xl` -> if width is greater than 640px apply `text-4xl` otherwise apply `text-8xl`. It's mobile first https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design

Comment: Tailwind is mobile-first, so all styles are applied to all viewport sizes, and breakpoints override the behavior for larger screens. Your Tailwind reads: "If the viewport width is greater than 640px set text-4xl. Otherwise set text-8xl."

Comment: doesnt that mean if i'm on mobile the text should be 4xl? and large/md screens is 8xl?

Comment: No, mobile is the default, you are specifying bigger screens. `sm` means more than 640 px

Comment: oh thank you for the help! i understood it the other way! it works now!

Answer (score 0):

To use the breakpoints in Tailwind, you target a specific breakpoint which applies that style to that breakpoint and [ALL breakpoints above that](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design#targeting-a-breakpoint-range).

> By default, styles applied by rules like md:flex will apply at that breakpoint and stay applied at larger breakpoints.

> If you’d like to apply a utility only when a specific breakpoint range is active, stack a responsive modifier like md with a max-* modifier to limit that style to a specific range.

So if you want the 8xl size to be applied for the larger screens and above, you need to use: `sm:text-4xl lg:text-8xl`.

Comment: I think that op really wanted `text-4xl sm:text-8xl`